# Creating mongo query in Spring using mongoTemplate

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, mongotemplate

I need help in 2 things.

> 1. Creating a Spring mongoquery from a mongo query using **spring mongo template**.
> 2. Filter the result and get only lower level objects from a document which has a json tree structure.
>
>    I only want to get a list of matching **merchant_shops** by passing
>      community_id,list of package_type_id and category_id.

I am using mongodb version 4.
 Thank you in advance.

Document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bdafff206ba681e30895e50"),
    "community_id" : "09a5c059-33b3-4e47-9905-709f5c244580",
    "package_types" : [ 
        {
            "package_type_id" : 1,
            "categories" : [ 
                {
                    "category_id" : "5bd0433d8ac2ce275082ff1f",
                    "subcategories" : [ 
                        {
                            "subcategory_id" : "5bd0436d8ac2ce275082ff20",
                            "merchant_shops" : [ 
                                {
                                    "shop_id" : "5bd19a704ab492427d7326a0",
                                    "distance" : 14.2841995007249
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "shop_id" : "5bd84aed4ab4926fb2060e76",
                                    "distance" : 14.283313487973
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "shop_id" : "5bdc14ad4ab492123f29c6a7",
                                    "distance" : 14.2829648551977
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "shop_id" : "5be9555e4ab4923a01c7b7f8",
                                    "distance" : 11.8215058435006
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "shop_id" : "5be95a974ab4923a01c7b7fc",
                                    "distance" : 11.8081739265758
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "package_type_id" : 3,
            "categories" : [ 
                {
                    "category_id" : "5bd0433d8ac2ce275082ff1f",
                    "subcategories" : [ 
                        {
                            "subcategory_id" : "5bd0436d8ac2ce275082ff20",
                            "merchant_shops" : [ 
                                {
                                    "shop_id" : "5bd84aed4ab4926fb2060e76",
                                    "distance" : 14.283313487973
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Query that works fine in mongodb:

```
db.getCollection('community_shop').aggregate([
    { $match: {"community_id": "09a5c059-33b3-4e47-9905-709f5c244580"} },
    { $project: 
       {
        package_types: 
           {$filter: {
            input: '$package_types',
            as: 'item',
            cond: {
               $or: [
                       {
                        $in: ['$$item.package_type_id', [1,3]]
                       },{
                          $eq: ['$$item.categories.category_id', "5bd0433d8ac2ce275082ff1f"] 
                         }
                    ]
                }
            }}
        }
    }
 ])
```

Java class is:

```
@Document(collection = "community_shop")
public class CommunityShopDOB {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Field("community_id")
    private String communityId;

    @Field("package_types")
    private List<PackageType> packageTypes;

    public static class PackageType {

        @Field("package_type_id")
        private Integer packageTypeId;

        @Field("categories")
        private List<Category> categories;

        public static class Category {

            @Field("category_id")
            private String categoryId;

            @Field("subcategories")
            private List<Subcategory> subcategories;

            public static class Subcategory {

                @Field("subcategory_id")
                private String subcategoryId;

                @Field("merchant_shops")
                private List<MerchantShop> merchantShops;

                public static class MerchantShop {

                    @Field("shop_id")
                    private String shopId;

                    @Field("distance")
                    private Double distance;

                    @Field("filter_value_ids")
                    private List<String> filterValueIds;
         }
     }
   }
}
```

My solution so far is and it is incorrect:

```
Criteria cr = Criteria.where("communityId").is(society_id);
            MatchOperation filterStates = Aggregation.match(cr);
            Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(filterStates, project("packageTypes")
                    .and(filter("packageTypes").as("item").by(valueOf("item.packageTypeId").equalToValue(1))

                    ).as("packageTypes"));

            AggregationResults<CommunityShopDOB> output = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, CommunityShopDOB.class,
                    CommunityShopDOB.class);
            return output.getUniqueMappedResult();
```

Comment: Well it's only "working fine" because you are not actually matching anything on the second condition of the `$or`. and that expression is actually incorrect. More to the direct point is "Where is your attempted code writing this with spring mongo?". There's plenty of spring mongodb aggregation examples around. So instead of asking someone to write all your code for you, it's usually far better received when you show what you attempted so far and which part you have trouble understanding.

Comment: Good point..i m stuck for a week. I have tried several times. I didn't get syntax for problem like this only.

Comment: I have updated the problem